# Positioning Problems with UIViews inside a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I am attempting to create a scrollable view for ios7.

I am going by all the examples I have found on the internet... using this approach

- UIView (Main View)

  - UIScrollView (obvious)

    - UIView (Container View)

       -All the other views

Here is what my IB looks like:

[image]

Here is what it looks like when I run my app:

[image]

I cannot figure out why the label is so low... Looking at the metrics in IB it says the Y is 100, but it should be something like 10... it's almost like it isn't taking into account that it's inside a container.

EDIT:

Here is what the IB looks like with colored backgrounds and Y=10 for my label:

[image]

Comment: Label has y position is 100pixels. It means 100pixels in axes of Container.

Please consider ScrollView and View position

Hope this helps you.

Comment: add different background colors (red, yellow, green, gray, white etc) to your UIView (mainView), UIScrollView (the obvious one), UIView (container view), and all the child views. You'll see which one is the culprit. Also remember, the text in your label is horizontally centered. (also your IB origin.y value is 100, not the 10 you are expecting). Add your screenshot after making it colorful. will be helpful for answering.

Comment: I guess that's the point in my question... I didn't set that 100... IB did... when I make it the 10 that I want it positions it under the nav bar